# Meteor collection Update not properly updating on client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to update a document. Specifically, I'm changing the order of items - an array of objects. The array is called 'resources'. I call a method to update the position of each object within the resources array. I can see from looking in the database that the document has been updated with the correct order.

On update, as expected, the client reacts - and updates with the new data - however, it appears to be displaying the array in the wrong order... its like its 'one out'... (so the item moved to index 2 appears at index 1... the item moved to index 3 appears at index 2 etc) yet when I do a physical refresh of the browser - the data loads as expected. Someone has a similar (but not identical) issue here - [Meteor collection insert not updating on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370706/meteor-collection-insert-not-updating-on-client) - although none of the answers have helped with my problem.

In my router.js file (I'm using ironrouter)

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  waitOn: function() {
   return [ Meteor.subscribe('playlists'), Meteor.subscribe('resources') ];
  }
});

.....

Router.route('/playlist/:_id', {
  name: 'playlistPage',
  data: function() { 
    return Playlists.findOne(this.params._id); 
  }
});
```

On the client I have:

```
          ...
'click #saveOrder': function(e, template) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var currentplaylistId = (template.data._id);

     var resourcesArray = [];
     $('#playlistTableBody tr').each(function(i) {
       var $this = $(this);
       var data = {
           title: $this.data('title'),
           type: $this.data('type'),
           resourceid: $this.data('resourceId'),
           duration: $this.data('duration'),
           order:  i
           }
           resourcesArray.push(data);
      });




Meteor.call('playlistUpdateResourceOrder', 
currentplaylistId, resourcesArray, function(error, result) {
    // display the error to the user and abort
     if (error)
     return throwError(error.reason);
     // Refresh data?
     Router.go('playlistPage', {_id: result._id});
});
```

and server

```
  playlistUpdateResourceOrder: function (currentplaylistId, resourcesArray) {
    Playlists.update(currentplaylistId, {
      $set: { resources: resourcesArray }
    });
    return {
      _id: currentplaylistId // return to our updated / renamed playlist
    };

  }
```

My templates are very simple:

```
   <tbody id="playlistTableBody">
  {{#each resources }}
    {{>resourceItem}}
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

and

```
<template name="resourceItem">
<tr data-title="{{title}}" data-type="{{type}}" data-resourceid="{{resourceId}}" data-duration="{{duration}}">
<td>{{title}}</td>
<td>{{type}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always sort data on the client. Because if you sort data in Meteor.publish, it will sort the data only on initial load.

Your template for showing sorted resources can look like this:

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
  {{#each resources}}
    {{>resourceItem}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

And your helper called *"resources"* that returns sorted resources:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
  resources: function() {
    return Resources.find({}, { sort: { order: 1 } });
  }
});
```

You can return your data in helper or router. Important part is:

```
//Always sort collection on the client
Resources.find({}, { sort: { order: 1 } });
```

**EDIT:** To sort subdocument, you can use Underscore function [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy). Underscore is in Meteor app by default:

```
var subDoc = [{ title: 'asdf', order: 2 }, { title: 'ah', order: 1 }];
//Sorting by order
var sorted = _.sortBy(subDoc, function(item) { 
  return item.order 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas - however, this is a sub-collection (an array of objects) and not a collection itself. I have a document, with a array called resources containing objects. Its this resources array that I want to update.

Comment: So what is Meteor.subscribe('resources') then? For sorting subdocument you can use Underscore sortBy function: http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: resources collection is something else - sorry, I should have commented that line out. What I don't get is - in my tbody  the resources array writes out in the wrong order. Yet if I put the same code on the page, outside of tbody.. it renders in the correct order. Its got to be something to do with the plugin (which affects tbody). I removed the plugin and tried manually manipulating the dom in Chrome debug (cut the first TR from the top, and pasted at the bottom). I then hit save - and got the same problem... so it seems to be whenever the dom is manipluated by jquery or bruce force by hand?

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. Getting data from HTML to JavaScript is not good. You already have rendered data in JavaScript so why you don't work with them? I don't see in your code where you get "resources", but I can see you are trying to get them from HTML via jQuery. It's bad. You should get them the same way as you pass them in template.

Comment: I'm using javascript to provide sortable functionality - then capturing the new sort order, and writing back to the subdocument. Having spoken with a few people, it seems meteor doesn't work so well with sub-documents, so I need to move every resource into its own collection.